# Splitting text gathered using .text()

Tags: javascript, text, split

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var dates = "July 5, 2016July 12, 2016";
            var splitted = dates.split(/\B(?=[A-Z])/);
           
            var k = [];
            for (i of splitted ) {
                k.push(i.match(/\d+(?=,)/)[0]); 
                // alert(typeof k);
            }
            if (k) {

                $.each(k, function(key, value) {
                    var date = value;
                        $(".fc-list-heading-main").append(date);
                });
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fc-list-heading-main"></div>

<div class="fc-list-heading-main"></div>
```

I'm working on this calendar of events for a website.The calendar gets messed up whenever there is more 1 event for a month. I'm working for a fix and got stuck on this one:

My code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fc-prev-button").click(function(){
            $('.fc-list-heading-main').each(function (index, value){
              var dates = $(".fc-list-heading-main").text();
                console.log(dates);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result:

[image]

How can I separate July 12, 2016 from July 5, 2016? I need to pass them as a separate date. Hope someone could help me on this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do those dates have a separate HTML elements in this calendar? Maybe there's more elements inside `.fc-list-heading-main`

Comment: .fc-list-heading-main is actually the span class where the text resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var dates = "July 5, 2016July 12, 2016";
            var splitted = dates.split(/\B(?=[A-Z])/);
           
            var k = [];
            for (i of splitted ) {
                k.push(i.match(/\d+(?=,)/)[0]); 
            }
            if (k) {
                $.each(k, function(key, value) {
                  $(".fc-list-heading-main").eq(key).append(value);
                });
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fc-list-heading-main"></div>

<div class="fc-list-heading-main"></div>
```

Comment: Wow man. Thanks. That saved me. All this time I was just missing the eq.(key). Care to explain?

Comment: `$(".fc-list-heading-main")` return two elements so you need to use `.eq(0)` to get the first one and change the text. Before you edited both elements at once.

Comment: Thanks man. I was hopeless about this a while ago. Yes, I will. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure FullCalendar has a method for getting those events in a nicer way.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/

There are couple of other methods but sth like this should work:

```
var dates = $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').map(
    function(calendarEvent){ return calendarEvent.start}
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already close to my goal but got stuck again on this part. Here's my code:

Comment: My problem is it's only returning the last element from the object and I can't figure out why it's happening. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say looking only on the script on pastebin. Please attach a snippet or jsfiddle to first post.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question. Please check. That's my current situation.

Comment: It should only be 5 and 12 for each iteration. Hope you can help me with this one.

Comment: @BenedictPayot try the snippet i just posted